# Can I suppress construction of a toc-file with beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents

It seems that beamer produces a .toc file by default. Can I suppress the creation of such a file?

Comment: Try adding `\nofiles` to your preamble.

Comment: Why the downvote? I also find the request a bit odd but it is a reasonable question.